# Symfony2 form in base.html.twig

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am new to Symfony2 and I am just trying some stuff to learn Symfony2.
Currently, I have a few controllers which can perfrom some simple tasks. A simple crud controller for example.

Al my pages extend a base.html.twig file and insert their block into it. Now I want to add a login part to my base file, because I want to be able to login at every page. I was thinking to use the formbuilder for this, but this is php code which can not be in a html.twig file. I have absolutly no idea how to handle this. Can someone push me in the right direction of give my some working example?

Thanking in advance

Actions:

```
public function loginFormAction(Request $request){

    // create a task and give it some dummy data for this example
    $message = "";
    $account = new Account();
    $account->setEmail('login@login.nl');

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($account)
        ->add('email', 'text')
        ->add('wachtwoord', 'text')
        ->add('login', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($_POST != null && $_POST['form']['email'] != null) {

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeBlogBundle:Account');
        $email =$_POST['form']['email'];
        $wachtwoord =$_POST['form']['wachtwoord'];
        $foundAccount = $repository->findOneByemail($email);

        if (!$foundAccount) {
            $message = "Ingevuld email en wachtwoord komen niet overeen.";
        }else if($foundAccount->getWachtwoord() == $wachtwoord){

            $session = $request->getSession();

            $session->set('name', $foundAccount->getVoornaam() . " " . $foundAccount->getAchternaam());
            $session->set('email', $foundAccount->getEmail());


            //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('melding', array('melding' => 'mooiman')));
            //return $this->render('AcmeBlogBundle:Account:melding.html.twig', array('melding' => 'Hallo, '.$foundAccount->getVoornaam() . " " . $foundAccount->getAchternaam()));

            $message = 'Hallo, '.$foundAccount->getVoornaam() . " " . $foundAccount->getAchternaam();
            $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->add('logout', 'submit')
                ->getForm();

            return $this->render('AcmeBlogBundle:Account:login.html.twig', array('form'=> $form->createView(), 'message' => $message));

        }else{
            $message = "Ingevuld email en wachtwoord komen niet overeen.";
        }


    }

    return $this->render('AcmeBlogBundle:Account:login.html.twig', array('form'=> $form->createView(), 'message' => $message));
}

public function logoutFormAction(Request $request){

    // create a task and give it some dummy data for this example
    $session = $request->getSession();

    $message = 'Hallo, '.$session->get('name');

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('logout', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($_POST != null) {
        $account = new Account();
        $account->setEmail('login@login.nl');

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($account)
            ->add('email', 'text')
            ->add('wachtwoord', 'text')
            ->add('login', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

        $session->set('name', null);
        $session->set('email', null);

        $message = "U bent nu uitgelogd";
    }

    return $this->render('AcmeBlogBundle:Account:login.html.twig', array('form'=> $form->createView(), 'message' => $message));
}
```

Base.html.twig:

```
{% if(app.session.get('name') == null) %}
    {{ render(controller('AcmeBlogBundle:Account:loginForm')) }}
{% else %}
    {{ render(controller('AcmeBlogBundle:Account:logoutForm')) }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include whole output of other controller/action in template. Just include this in your taplate:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    {{ render(controller('YourBundle:User:login')) }}
</div>
```

This will inject whole output of YourBundle/UserController/loginAction to the #sidebar div. Remember that YourBundle/UserController/loginAction template can't extend other twig templates and hould be simple.

You can read more about embedding controllers here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

[EXAMPLE]:

An form action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/contact", name="contact")
 */
public function contactAction(Request $request){

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('contact'))
        ->add('email', 'email', array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email()
            )
        ))
        ->add('add', 'submit')
        ->getForm()
        ;

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            //do whatever you want and redirect
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage'));
        }else{
            // this must be a full page (extending from base tamplate)
            // that show form and errors
            return $this->render(
                'YourBundle:ControllerName:contact_faild.html.twig',
                array('form' => $form->createView())
            );
        }
    }

    return $this->render(
        'YourBundle:ControllerName:contact.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView())
    );
}
```

There must be action URL in form "->setAction($this->generateUrl('contact'))" because form should be handled on separate request.

Next a form template (YourBundle:ControllerName:contact.html.twig):

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

Then we need an extra template for showing form errors when something went wrong. That should extend base template and probably override place where form appear in the first time
A form with errors tempalte (YourBundle:ControllerName:contact_faild.html.twig):

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block sidebar -%}
{{ form(form) }}
{% endblock sidebar %}
```

And base teplate:

```
(...)
{% block sidebar %}
<div id="sidebar">
    {{ render(controller('ClickAdUserBundle:User:contact')) }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
(...)
```

Comment: thanks, this is very usefull. But unfortunately i cannot redirect from login now. How to solve that?

Comment: You should be able to redirect. Do you get any error massages?

Comment: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Error when rendering "http://symfony.dev/app_dev.php/" (Status code is 302).") in ::base.html.twig at line 13.

Comment: that's because your request has been processed in current controller. You should have form action URL pointing to login controller. Form should be processed in separate request.

Comment: I do not completly understand that. I added my code to the question, maybe you can give me some advice on what i am doing wrong.

Comment: first of all I recommend you to check this complete [user bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle). It will handle authentication for you app. I have updated my answer (see above). You should add setAction('name_of_your_login_rout') to the login form to handle login action in separate request. Then you can redirect anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html)
you will find some html/twig code, put that in a "login.html.twig" and include it where you want

Answer (score 0):

If you're completly new to Symfony2 i can suggest the [symfony2 symblock tutorial](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/configuration-and-templating.html)

You'll work with Doctrine 2, creating Forms and design them, Twig Layouts and all the other stuff while creating a little blog.

Taken from the example, you would create the form in your controller like this

```
// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Controller/PageController.php
public function contactAction()
{
    $enquiry = new Enquiry(); //This creates an Instance of the Entity you need for the form
    $form = $this->createForm(new EnquiryType(), $enquiry);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // Perform some action, such as sending an email

            // Redirect - This is important to prevent users re-posting
            // the form if they refresh the page
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('BloggerBlogBundle_contact'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:contact.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

and the form as .html.twig would look like this

```
{# src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Resources/views/Page/contact.html.twig #}
{% extends 'BloggerBlogBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Contact{% endblock%}

{% block body %}
    <header>
        <h1>Contact symblog</h1>
    </header>

    <p>Want to contact symblog?</p>

    <form action="{{ path('BloggerBlogBundle_contact') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} class="blogger">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}

        {{ form_row(form.name) }}
        {{ form_row(form.email) }}
        {{ form_row(form.subject) }}
        {{ form_row(form.body) }}

        {{ form_rest(form) }}

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I hardly suggest working through this tutorial to have a nice start with symfony2